# Default Error Page PHP 500 errors in Apache

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, wsod

I want to set a Default Error Page for a Server 500 message / error.

I set the entry in my vhost:

ErrorDocument 500 /errorpage.html

I created a PHP File with an unknown function to get a 500 error. This works. The Apache sends a 500 status code in the browser and on the access.log file. 
But my redirect to the errorpage.html isn´t working. I see a whitepage (WSOD) without any content.

Where is my mistake ?

To test the default error page I also created a example.html file an made this file unreadable for the webserver user (file rights 600, owner root). The browser / apache sends me the 401 status an my default error page 401 is working. 
I got the redirect to my errorpage.html (ErrorDocument 401 /errorpage.html)

It must be something with my PHP / Apache configuration.

PHP 5.5.9, apache 2.4

Comment: Yep, same problem. Thanks.